# What is a "zamposta"?

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales

**What is a "zamposta"?**

I stumbled upon this in the following article:

[**"Os Maios de Villafranca del Bierzo se ‘levantaron’ al sol de una tradición milenaria"**](https://www.infobierzo.com/os-maios-de-villafranca-del-bierzo-se-levantaron-al-sol-de-una-tradicion-milenaria/391707/)

In case you cannot link to the article, it appeared in the following sentence:

> Los ‘maios’ se han tumbado por las calles para levantarse al ritmo de ‘Levántate maio bastante dormiche, pasa un burro e non o sentiche’, la popular canción que les acompaña durante este día para reclamar en los balcones de las viviendas, castañas, caramelos o monedas a las “doncellas” y “cabaleiros”, **o reprender a las “roñosas” o “zampostas”.**

For various reasons, I’m assuming the word is Galician.  However, after consulting several Galician dictionaries (albeit only ones I can access online and for free), I was not able to find the word.  Dictionaries/sources I consulted include:

[**Glosbe's Galician-English Dictionary**](https://glosbe.com/gl/en/zamposta)

[**Langoland's Galician Dictionary**](http://galician.galego.free.fr/index_uk.htm)

[**Diccionario Abierto de Gallego**](https://www.significadode.org/gallego/zamposta.htm)

[**Google Translate**](https://translate.google.com/#gl/en/zamposta)

In a search of Google Books, I could only find one legitimate instance of it — where it was fully spelled out in one word.  However, the book appears to be written in Finnish, [**for which Google Translate seems to think "Zamposta" is the name of a dog kennel.**](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/John%20Sj%C3%B6berg%20kertoi%20oikeudelle%20oivallisesta%20ruumiskoirastaan%20Zamposta%3A%20koira%20oli%20ilmaissut%20koko%20joukon%20paikkoja%2C%20joihin%20Quick%20oli%20v%C3%A4itt%C3%A4nyt%20k%C3%A4tkeneens%C3%A4%20Johanin%20ruumiinosia.%20Ja%20jos%20oikeudelle%20tulisi%20mieleen%20ihmetell%C3%A4%2C%20miksi%20mit%C3%A4%C3%A4n%20ei%20ollut%20l%C3%B6ytynyt%20...)

I suppose I could try to contact the person who wrote the article since this word seems to be so elusive, but my success with such inquiries has been abysmally low (plus the author of this article doesn't even add their name to it!), so I thought I'd post this here to see what can be dug up in the sage beehive of a mind that is the Spanish StackExchange.

---

**¿Qué significa "zamposta"?**

Me topé con ésta en el siguiente artículo:

[**"Os Maios de Villafranca del Bierzo se ‘levantaron’ al sol de una tradición milenaria"**](https://www.infobierzo.com/os-maios-de-villafranca-del-bierzo-se-levantaron-al-sol-de-una-tradicion-milenaria/391707/)

En caso de que no puedas enlazar al artículo, aparece en la siguiente oración:

[Véanse arriba.]

Por diversos razones, estoy asumiendo que la palabra es gallega.  Sin embargo, tras consultar varios diccionarios gallegos (los únicos a los que pude acceder en línea y gratis), no pude encontrar la palabra.  Los diccionarios/fuentes consultados incluyen:

[Véanse arriba.]

En una búsqueda de Google Books, sólo pude encontrar una instancia legítima de ella — donde era plenamente escrita en una palabra.  No obstante, el libro parece escrito en finlandés, [**para que Google Translate parece pensar que “Zamposta” es el nombre de una perrera.**](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/John%20Sj%C3%B6berg%20kertoi%20oikeudelle%20oivallisesta%20ruumiskoirastaan%20Zamposta%3A%20koira%20oli%20ilmaissut%20koko%20joukon%20paikkoja%2C%20joihin%20Quick%20oli%20v%C3%A4itt%C3%A4nyt%20k%C3%A4tkeneens%C3%A4%20Johanin%20ruumiinosia.%20Ja%20jos%20oikeudelle%20tulisi%20mieleen%20ihmetell%C3%A4%2C%20miksi%20mit%C3%A4%C3%A4n%20ei%20ollut%20l%C3%B6ytynyt%20...)

Supongo que podría intentar contactar la persona que escribió el artículo dado que esta palabra parece ser tan elusiva, pero mi éxito con tales investigaciones ha sido extremadamente bajo (además, ¡el autor de este artículo ni siquiera firmó con su nombre!), así que pensé en publicar esto aquí para ver qué pueda ser desenterrado en la sabia mente colmena que es el Spanish StackExchange.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79435/discussion-on-question-by-lisa-beck-what-is-a-zamposta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le he preguntado a una amiga gallega a ver si conoce esa palabra, pero mientras tanto te diré que esa tradición de pedir regalos y reprender a quienes no te los dan no es exclusiva de Galicia. Hay un villancico típico que se canta en España, que dice así:

> Dame el [aguinaldo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1FBz3Iz), carita de rosa
>   que no tienes cara de ser tan [roñosa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WhPdp3H).

La palabra *roñoso* se usa principalmente de dos formas:

- Cuando algo está roñoso es que está lleno de [roña](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WhCP710), es decir, de suciedad.
- Cuando alguien es roñoso es que es un [tacaño](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Yuib8De).

Nótese que alguien tacaño es alguien que [escatima](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GDHe2xv) en el gasto. Luego si vas por ahí pidiendo [dádivas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bp3lFve) a los vecinos, normal que quieras agradecérselo a aquellos que te las dan, y tachar de avariciosos a los que no. Por tanto, una persona *zamposta* será alguien que entra en esta segunda categoría, si la ponen como sinónima de *roñosa*.

Comment: Sí uso *roña* como suciedad pero no roñoso, para mi algo que "está roñoso" es algo oxidado.

Comment: @blonfu de hecho, esa es precisamente la tercera acepción de "roñoso". :-)

Comment: @Charlie  Tras un examen más detallado, ahora veo que _roñosa_ muy bien podría ser un sinónimo de _zamposta_.  Me gusta mucho tu forma de pensar y el extento a que te esforzabas para responder a esta pregunta.  Puedo fácilmente otorgarte la marca verde.

Comment: @LisaBeck ¡gracias! Aclarar que mi amiga me comentó que no conocía la palabra "zamposta".

Comment: @Charlie Pues, gracias por preguntarle.  Supongo que todavía no soy el [**Pepe Carvalho**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepe_Carvalho) de los misterios de la lengua española, pero tal vez algún día ... Por cierto, ahora me doy cuenta que "extento" no es una palabra en español.  Debería haber escrito "la medida en que ...", pero claramente me entendiste.